# Using Angularjs with Breeze

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I have been using angularjs with webapi services. I am little confused about breeze. What does it do? What is the advantage of using it from what I am currently using.
I tried to search online to remove this confusion but haven't found a good article that would explain this. Please let me know any resources that can be helpful in gaining some knowledge about it.

Comment: The excellent course on Pluralsight by John Papa is a must.  There is also a very good course there by Brian Noyes on building a SPA with Breeze.  He uses Knockout but the coverage of Breeze's features is quite good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [This page pretty much sums it up](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/features)

*These two short read should also allow you to glean some understanding of how breeze was intended to be used and why:*

#### [OData vs WebApi](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/odata-vs-webapi)

#### [Concurrent Saves](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/concurrent-saves)

From my limited experience/uses it really shines when:

1. Creating an client side app that is required to run on less than latest browsers. *(otherwise I would lean more towards websockets/firebase)*
2. Included in an application with a more than 3 entity types and a lot of PUT requests.  Breeze's change tracking, queries and batched saves are a godsend

The creators of Breeze will have a lot more things to say about this product and its uses/strong points -- they do some great work and also build apps that are more heavily used than what I build.